# Do open sets contain limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If set B is a set of limit points of set A and if A is open, can A contain any of the points in B, assuming A is open?

Comment: Are you asking if an open set contains all of its limit points, or if an open set has to contain at least one of its limit points?

Comment: The latter. Does an open set contain any limit points?

Comment: Let A =(0,1).  Then B=[0,1].  A contains nothing *but* limit points!

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, consider the set $\{0\}\cup \{1/n \mid n>0\}$ in the subspace topology.  Then the set $\{1/n \mid n>0\}$ is open (being the intersection of $(0,2)$ with our subspace), but its only limit point is $0$, which is not in it.  Of course, with open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$, every element is a limit point

Comment: An open set can contain none, some, or all of the limit points.  The empty set contains none of its limit points.  The open interval contains all but two of its limit points.  The real numbers contain all its limit points.

Comment: So, if A is any subset of R, A is sure to contain some limit points?

Comment: Let A =(0,1),B =[0,1]. We know a set (X $\tau$)  has limit points iff it is closed. So obviously B does. So according to what I quoted how does A have limit points. ?

Answer (score 2):

A point x (need not be in A) is a limit point if there exists a sequence (apart from constant sequence) that converge to x.
So if A=(0,1) then B will be A U {0,1} i.e B=[0,1].
Hence A contains some points of B.

I assume you are confusing limit point with boundary points,which is defined as those limit points not in A

Answer (score 0):

Take $A = ]0,1[$. Then $B = [0,1]$ which has a non-empty intersection with $A$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm visualizing set A as a circle and I assume everything within the boundary of the circle as an interior point of A. I'm also assuming that the boundary itself is not part of A which can be termed as A's limit points. And B contains only the limit points of A.

I know what I'm visualizing is not the preferred way to do it but is there some other way I can understand this?

Comment: @tinkuge You can view $A$ as a circle and $B$ points that are "infinitely close" to $A$.

Comment: However close the points of B may be, they're still not part of A, are they?

Comment: @tinkuge Some points in $B$ may be parts of $A$, some may not.

Comment: Why are you visualizing A as a circle when it's a line segment?  A is all the points between 0 and 1 but not including 0 and 1.  A has uncountable many limit points.  0, 1 and every value in between is a limit point.  All but 0 and 1 are in A.

Comment: I guess that explains my flawed understanding of limit points. I have very little formal background in Mathematics i.e., high school level. So, how would you define limit points with respect to a number line?