# Inverse image of an open set is open under continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity, set-theory

We know, for continuous functions, the inverse image of an [open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#:%7E:text=edit-,A%20topology,is%20called%20an%20open%20set.%5B3%5D,-%EF%BF%BD) is open.

I first thought that the following statement is incorrect but the key to the question says it is true.
The statement is

> There exist a continuous function $f:A \to B$ such that $f^{-1}(B) = A$, where $B$ is open and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ but $A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to construct the example

Consider the function $$ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\ f(x) = \tan ^{-1}x $$

What is the range of this function? An open interval $(-π/2 ,π/2)$ right?

Now if we take the inverse of $f$
i.e. $f^{-1} = \tan(y)  ; y \in   \text{ co-domain } $

Then I think the inverse image of the set $(-π/2 ,π/2)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ under $f^{-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is a [closed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set#:%7E:text=A%20closed%20set%20contains%20its%20own%20boundary.%20In%20other%20words%2C%20if%20you%20are%20%22outside%22%20a%20closed%20set%2C%20you%20may%20move%20a%20small%20amount%20in%20any%20direction%20and%20still%20stay%20outside%20the%20set.%20This%20is%20also%20true%20if%20the%20boundary%20is%20the%20empty%20set%2C%20e.g.%20in%20the%20metric%20space%20of%20rational%20numbers%2C%20for%20the%20set%20of%20numbers%20of)

This is example is wrong due to my wrong understanding of $\mathbb{R}$ to be closed ( as the comment below says).

What can be an example in the favour of the statement?

---

I now less about topology and definition of closed and open for me are

A set is **closed** if it contains all of its limit points.

And a set is **open** if there is any limit point that lie outside the set.

Kindly help. Thank You.

**Edit:** I have edited the question to ask about the example too in favour of the statement.

Comment: You are wrong to think that closed sets cannot be open, $\mathbb{R}$ is open too. Also, your definition of open does not correspond to the standard definition of open sets.

Comment: According to your definition $\mathbb{R}$ would indeed not be open. How have you come up with that definition?

Comment: I see. I just took that closed and open sets are just opposite of each other, (which is wrong) i checked it now . There can be open set that contain all, none or a few of its limit points. [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2036897/1183233] . Thank You for suggestions.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and $U\subseteq Y$ is open, then $f^{-1}[U]$ is open. This always holds and in fact, if $f^{-1}[U]$ is open for all open $U\subseteq Y$ then $f$ is continuous. This is equivalent definition of continuity